# Configure ZArchiver app to continue operation on error & write log file

Tags: applications, backup, usb, sd-card

I use Samsung Galaxy S10+ on Android 12. In the phone, a 256 GB SD card is plugged in. A USB hub is connected to the USB-C OTG of the phone. In a USB-A, the USB stick is plugged in. For the target, I use Transcend 512 GB with blue status LED formatted FAT32. Now, due to the worsening in Android, most apps are no longer able to write to USB.

After many days of googling and trying, I have found ZArchiver. It can write to USB. The problem is: when ZArchiver on the source device finds an object it cannot read, ZArchiver finishes and displays the error message

> ... .nomedia ... open failed.

I need to set up ZArchiver to continue copying and to write the error message into a log file.

Some more details.

1. I have repeated all, again I have chosen "copy" (but not compress).

   In one window, the SD card source device `/storage/3530-3234/` is marked all (which are the displayed directories directly below `/storage/3530-3234`).

   In the other window, the target `/mnt/media_rw/1D!A-1692/`. This is empty.

   ZArchiver is working and displays the directory it is working on, always the directory directly below of `/storage/3530-3234/`, no subdirectories. And it displays the progress: e.g. 25% in 5 minutes. That seems to be too fast. On the SD card source device, 81 GB of 238 GB is used. Other apps take many hours. After 7 minutes, ZArchiver aborted with an error message:

   > Action completed with errors

   This is not followed by a long list, but by only one event:

   ```
   .nomedia

   1 storage/3530/-3234/Android/data/.nomedia: open failed: ENDENT (No such file or directory)
   ```

   In the target, 18 directories (direct below `/storage/3530-3234/`) were created. These are correct copies, including subdirs and files.
2. I have repeated all, and now I have chosen "compress 7z" (but not copy).

   ZArchiver is working and displays the directory it is working on, always the directory directly below of `/storage/3530-3234/`, no subdirectories. And it displays the progress. After some time, ZArchiver aborted with an error message:

   > Action completed with errors

   This is followed by a long list:

   ```
   3530-3234.7z

   1 errno=2: No such file or dir: 
   Android/data!com.google.androud.apps.maps/
   ...
   101 errno=2: No such file ...
   ```

   In this list, it doesn't include `.nomedia`.

   In the target, only one directory was created: `.HhT...` (encrypted). This directory contains one file:

   ```
   .nomedia
   512 B  08.01.24 22:00
   ```